# What does vector minus vector actually mean

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

Trying to understand (did not take many math classes, so I apologize I know I should know this) what it means when I have some code that takes 2 vectors and subtracts one from the other to equal a new vector. I kind of get what a vector in unity is, it's like a point with 3 numbers that represent it's position in the world. But what I am confused about is when I have this for instance

```
Transform target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
```

So I obviously know what subtraction means, but what I am trying to understand is what the new targetDir is since you're subtracting 2 points, not numbers. Do you simply just minus the equivalent axis (x-x, y-y, z-z) and that gives you the new vector?

Comment: You absolutely *need* to understand vector algebra if you're going to develop a game. If you don't, stop right there and find yourself a math class or online tutorial where you can learn it. Don't even try to make a game without knowing what vectors are, what they do and how they work.

Comment: Well I think that statement is a bit off since I have made games, none of which required vector algebra. I've created a poker algorithm as well and I haven't taken any college math classes, nor have I did anything above algebra in high school. You'd be surprised what people can learn. However, for AI, yes you are right. I am still a student though keep in mind, I haven't finished taking all my classes yet. I know I have to take a bunch of math, but for some reason they didn't make calculus a pre req for Game Ai Programming. I'm well aware I should have all of this down which is why I'm here :D

Comment: Hm, I should have mentioned I'm talking about 3D games. Of course, you don't **need** vectors for static games like Poker or games with little graphics display. But if you're gonna create a 3D game world (which kinda is the purpose of Unity3D), Vectors are essential. Depending on the game, an AI can be created without using Vectors, but if the AI character can move in some game world, you're back at needing vectors. Don't get me wrong, I know everyone has to learn. But I think StackOverflow is rather a place for specific problems and not for general learning purposes.

Comment: I had a specific problem, trying to understand code, I needed to understand this first to know what it was doing. Thanks for your concern though, the question was already answered! :D

Comment: I know, but I noticed your problem might (and probably does) come from a lack of knowledge about the topic "vectors" as a whole, which might lead to many more problems along your path. I think you interpreted my comment as more aggressive than it was intended. What I was trying to say is that it would probably be easier for you to learn all about vectors first and then start with Unity3D. There are several concepts in Unity that are really hard to grasp unless you know how vectors work.

Comment: Oh no I completely understand and 100% agree with you. I shouldn't be in this class. But I am, and I don't get less than a B, so I need to figure it out.

Comment: Oh, i see :D well, then good luck! We'll do what we can ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An image speaks more than a thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: Yes. Subtraction of vectors is equivalent to a composition of subtraction of their components, or in other words, P2 - P1 = { x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1 }.

http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors.html